# what happens to the electrons in low-voltage conductivity of salt water

Tags: electrochemistry, aqueous-solution, electrolysis

Suppose you take a 100 millivolt voltage source, and connect it using a pair of copper wires to a bath of salt water.

A current will flow through the water. If I'm not getting things completely wrong, it is possible to leave the experiment running for enough time that say 10 Coloumbs of charge will pass through.

If I'm not getting things completely wrong, there will be a voltage gradient of about 100mV across the bath, which will pull positive ions towards the negative electrode and negative ions towards the positive electrode. Electrons will move from the negative terminal of the voltage source towards the negative electrode and from the positive electrode to the positive terminal of the voltage source.

Now the question - what happens to the electrons that reach the negative electrode, and from where do the electrons that get to the positive electrode come from?

One possible answer would be electrolysis of stuff in the water, but with the voltage so low, I can't see where the energy to electrolyse things would come from.

Another answer, that I've never read of but I think might be true, is that copper might dissolve from the positive electrode, giving off an electron, and plate on the negative electrode. This will be hard to see because 10 Coloumbs of Copper ions is like 3 milligrams of copper, so not a lot. This doesn't consume energy, because in equilibrium, concentration and electric potential will balance the inherent energy of the $Cu^{2+}_{aq} + 2 e^{-}_{copper} \leftrightarrow Cu_{s}$ reaction. Is this correct?

[image]

Comment: (+1) Have you actually measured the current flow with 100 mV applied potential and saltwater electrolyte? This is very easy to do and would be informative. I do not see how copper could be oxidized at the anode and copper ions reduced at the cathode: there should not be any redox reactions happening at the applied potential.

Comment: This voltage is too low to cause chemical decomposition. Just remember that with direct current, whenever current flows in the external circuit, electrolysis (=chemical decomposition by redox process) *must* occur in the cell.

Comment: It is not directly the voltage, but any created .H radicals. The latter, embedded on Al have been implemented to convert PbS to Pb and H2S. The embedded H was the result of an acid/metal process, chemical not electro in nature but no difference. Here Cu2O + 2 .H to Cu and H2O, same reaction! Reference is in Hydrometallury,

Comment: Reference Link: " PbS + 2 •H = Pb + H2S (5) "  (see https://books.google.com/books?id=1etfSdk55SYC&pg=PA818&lpg=PA818&dq=what+metals+react+with+hcl+to+form+nascent+hydrogen&source=bl&ots=yEBZaIFL_T&sig=9383ZW7NCXAoSNmmny2sdrxXIF0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjEjpnWjejaAhVP4VMKHe1gBZE4FBDoAQg6MAU#v=onepage&q=what%20metals%20react%20with%20hcl%20to%20form%20nascent%20hydrogen&f=false ). Copy link, reaction is bottom of page.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you do not have pure copper wires, as likely air exposure has added a less bright presence of $\ce{Cu2O}$. Even better, use copper tubing, which if not very tarnished, heat them in air. Also, in this experiment, I recommend pre-boiling the solution formed from adding salt to distilled water to remove any dissolved oxygen content.

So, in your very low voltage experiment, what I expect (based on my galvanic copper battery cell experimentations) is that the cuprous layer on the electrode receiving the electrons is reduced to copper metal:

> $\ce{ H+ (aq) +  e- (aq) ->  .H (aq) }$

> $\ce{ Cu2O (s) +  2 .H (aq) ->  2 Cu (s)  + H2O}$

So, expect your electrodes to no longer look exactly the same (based on my related experience, it looks like someone cleaned one), an electrode could be visibly more bright from a small amount of fresh copper formation.

Now, what could occur if all the cuprous oxide is consumed? I cited [a source](http://www.diva-portal.se/smash/get/diva2:730237/FULLTEXT01.pdf), Page 29, Table 2.1 with a correspondingly slow reaction, the dissipation of a solvated electron in water:

> $\ce{ H2O (l) +  e- (aq) -> .H  + OH- (aq) }$

where the hydrogen radical could either self react liberating hydrogen gas or, per the nature of the metal present, become surface embedded.

Caution: If you wish to run this experiment at high voltage, please note that the resulting chlorine formation interacting with water may create some hypochlorous acid (HOCl). The  latter HOCl does react directly with copper metal. To [quote a source](https://journals.asm.org/doi/10.1128/mBio.01905-20#:%7E:text=The%20reaction%20between%20copper%20and,manganese%20(66%2C%2067).):

> The reaction between copper and HOCl is known to generate strong oxidizing intermediates, most likely highly reactive Cu(III) (59–63). HOCl is also capable of oxidizing other transition metals, including iron (64, 65) and manganese (66, 67).

The presence of copper ions can present disposal issues as such ions are quite toxic to select organism (like fish) and even to plants,.etc.

See if you could actually verify my expectations on the electrodes.

Comment: Check the quoted reaction, it is not balanced.

Comment: The actual mechanics is via the .H radical cited as the major reducing species in solutions.

Comment: A good source for radical chemistry is Buxton, and the hydrogen atom is discussed. To quote:

"The hydrogen atom is the conjugate acid of e-(aq), and it is the major reducing species in acidic solution, Eq. (3).

e-(aq) + H3O+ ---> H (aq) (3) "

Comment: A galvanic version of this reaction is simply place Cu tube (or old copper penny) and a piece of carbon in NaCl with a bit of lemon juice.  Microwave and in minutes the Cu anode is as bright as a new copper penny,

Comment: Related reaction: Reference Link: " PbS + 2 •H = Pb + H2S (5) "  (see https://books.google.com/books?id=1etfSdk55SYC&pg=PA818&lpg=PA818&dq=what+metals+react+with+hcl+to+form+nascent+hydrogen&source=bl&ots=yEBZaIFL_T&sig=9383ZW7NCXAoSNmmny2sdrxXIF0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjEjpnWjejaAhVP4VMKHe1gBZE4FBDoAQg6MAU#v=onepage&q=what%20metals%20react%20with%20hcl%20to%20form%20nascent%20hydrogen&f=false ). Copy link, reaction is bottom of page.

Comment: So the anode copper will be oxidized to produce circuit electrons, and that will produce the energy needed to reduce random stuff at the cathode?